# Creating a sub menu using String/char?

Tags: java

```
public static String getSubMenu(String submenu){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String chosen="", A="A",B="B", a="a", b="b";
        do{
        chosen = keyboard.next();
        keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\n\n");
        }while(chosen.compareTo(A));
        return chosen;
    }
    //This function below is fine.
    public static void Menu(){
        String unem="";
        do{
        System.out.println("Sub Menu");
        System.out.println("Select an Option\n\n");
        System.out.println("a.Sort by name\n" +                            
                           "b.Sort by time\n" +
                           "c.Exit sub-menu\n\n");
        System.out.print("Input the number for the selected option: ");
        unem= getSubMenu(unem);
        if("a".equals(unem)|| "A".equals(unem)){

        }
        if("b".equals(unem)|| "B".equals(unem)){

        }
    }while ("a".equals(unem) ||"b".equals(unem) || "A".equals(unem) || "B".equals(unem));

    }

}
```

Hi, I'm trying to make a sub menu. As you can see in the function `Menu`, when `getSubMenu` is called the user has to input a selected option in the function `getSubMenu`. I looked through my textbook and online and it doesn't seem you can use `char` within arguments such as

```
char a="a";
if(a != b);
```

If you can use characters instead of strings in the functions above please tell.

But moving on. What I am trying to do now is to get `getSubMenu` to return a String containing either `'A' || 'a' || 'b' || 'B' || 'c' || 'C'` and then loop when the user does not put any of these as an input. I've tried attempting to use `compareTo` but I receive a `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean error` how can I improve on this. What syntax can I use so that this can work.

Thanks for everyone who will help and contribute to this.

EDITED: NEW WORKING FUNCTION

```
  public static String getSubMenu(String submenu){
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean looped = true;
            String chosen="";
            do{
            chosen = keyboard.next();
            keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.print("\n\n");
            if("a".equals(option)|| "A".equals(option) || "b".equals(option)|| "B".equals(option) || "c".equals(option)|| "C".equals(option)){
                looped = false;
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Wrong input");
            }while(looped);
            return option;
```

It may of not been what I was aiming for but it still did it job.

Comment: It should be `char a='a'` , single quotes !

Answer (score 1):

`while(chosen.compareTo(A))` is where you should get an error . The method `compareTo(String)`  returns an `int` which you cannot use in `while(boolean expression)` , it requires a boolean expression which shall evaluate to `true` or `false`. I am pasting a code for reference , improvise on it :

```
 public static String getSubMenu(String submenu) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"A","B","C"});
    do {
        chosen = keyboard.next();
        keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\n\n");
    } while (chosen!=null && list.contains(chosen.toUpperCase()));
    return chosen;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense. So I can see why the loop wasn't function properly due to wrong variables.

Answer (score 0):

`compareTo()` compares 2 objects and returns an int that represents which object was greater. Since it is not a boolean your `do while` loop fails to compile. If you're looking for a specific input from the user, use this snippet.

```
        do
        {
            chosen = keyboard.next();
            keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.print("\n\n");
        }
        while (!chosen.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("a"));
```

You'll need to `trim()` the string to remove characters like whitespaces and you can use `equalsIgnoreCase()` to match 'A' and 'a'.